# Spring Property Consolidation

Tags: java, spring

I've got a Spring bean:

```
<bean id="sharedBean" class="com.bean.SharedBean">
    <constructor-arg name="app-name" value="#{ config['app.name'] }"/>
</bean>
```

This bean is defined in a jar and used in two apps that both get deployed to the same tomcat server. I've only got one properties file the apps share and I'd like to keep it that way if possible. You might see the problem - I need two values for app.name (one for each web app).

I need to set the app.name independently in each app. I don't mind hard coding the value in the Java (but don't think I can inject the value in that direction). I know I can introduce another properties file at a different path and override but I'm hoping there is a better way I can accomplish this through Spring that will allow me to maintain only one shared properties file.

Comment: if you have 'app.name' key in your properties file and you have loaded this file using <context:property-placeholder />, then you can use <constructor-arg name="app-name" value="${app.name}" />. what is config in your code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions, in recommended order:

1 - is there a reason why the shared bean is declared in a separate jar file?  Certainly, the bean class can be located there, but why not declare the actual bean inside the individual web apps where it's being used?

2 - if you absolutely need to keep the bean definition in the shared jar you can use [bean inheritance](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-configuration-inheritance/); (a) change your bean class to use a property rather than a constructor arg:

```
<bean id="sharedBean" class="com.bean.SharedBean">
    <property name="app-name" value="default"/>
</bean>
```

(b) in your web app context file:

```
<bean id="instanceBean" parent="sharedBean">
    <property name="app-name" value="app1"/>
</bean>
```

3 - use a Spring profile; in your shared jar context.xml:

```
<beans profile="app1">
    <bean id="sharedBean" class="com.bean.SharedBean">
        <constructor-arg name="app-name" value="app1"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="app2">
    <bean id="sharedBean" class="com.bean.SharedBean">
        <constructor-arg name="app-name" value="app2"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

note: <beans profile=... MUST be the last entries in your context file.
```

Add a context param to each web.xml (changing value as appropriate):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>app1</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Solution 2 worked a treat. Thanks for the response - much appreciated.